# How to build an update email function in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to refactor the `update` action in my Rails action, so that `users` can change their own email address only after confirming it by clicking on a link that I send to them.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorized_user

  def update
    current_email = @user.email
    new_email = params[:user][:email].downcase.to_s
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])    
      if new_email != current_email
        @user.change_email(current_email, new_email)     
        flash[:success] = "Please click on the link that we've sent you."
      else
        flash[:success] = "User updated."
      end
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def confirm_email
    @user = User.find_by_email_token!(params[:id])
    @user.email = @user.new_email
    @user.save
  end

  private

  def authorized_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

end
```

This function saves the new email to a database field `new_email`. `email` will be replaced only after the user has confirmed his `new_email` through a URL:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def change_email(old_email, new_email)
    self.email = old_email
    self.new_email = new_email.downcase    
    self.send_email_confirmation_link  
  end

end
```

The code partially works, but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this, maybe by using an `after_save` callback or at least moving more code to the model.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

P.S. Please don't suggest to use `Devise` for this. I really want to build my own authentication system here :-)

Comment: Huh, but doesn't `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` update the email field already? You will have the same value in `email` and `new_email`. Anyway, you could use a `before_save` callback and compare the current email address with the submitted email address in the callback. It may make your code look cleaner. Disadvantage could be that it's not immediately obvious what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I would love to see what the callback you're suggesting might look like!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you against using ActiveRecord callbacks to perform business logic: ActiveRecord models should only be a thin wrapper around the database persistence layer.

Look at how the controller code can be changed:

```
def update
  if UpdatesUserCheckingEmail.new(@user, params[:user], flash).execute!
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

All the business logic is performed by an external object, which encapsulates all your business logic (which you can put in app/services/updates_user_checking_email.rb)

```
class UpdatesUserCheckingEmail
  attr_reader :user, :user_params, :flash

  def initialize(user, user_params, options = {})
    @user = user
    @user_params = user_params
    @flash = options[:flash]
  end

  def execute!
    if user.update_attributes(user_params)
      if new_email != current_email
        user.change_email(current_email, new_email)     
        flash[:success] = "Please click on the link that we've sent you."
      else
        flash[:success] = "User updated."
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def current_email
    user.email
  end

  def new_email
    user_params[:email].downcase.to_s
  end

end
```

I'd also advise you to move the logic which sends the email out of the ActiveRecord model and inside a dedicated service object. This will make your app much more easier to change (and to test) in the future!

You can find a lot more about these concepts here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not check `current_email` and `new_email` after update in database because it should before the database update. Another one is you are sending link to user after updating email to the database. So, that could not meet your goal i.e. "email will be replaced only after the user has confirmed his `new_email` through a URL." You should create new action for updating user email or you should write logic for updating user email when user get email of "reset email" in update action of UserController. Following is something simple approach to resolve your problem:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def send_email_rest
    @user.change_email(@user.email, params[:new_email]) if params[:new_email].present?
  end
  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])  
      #stuff you want to do
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: OK, thanks. I've added to my code above to show how a user can confirm their own email address in my app. This has been working quite well so far.